# An application of Rouche's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots, rouches-theorem

I am studying for an exam in complex analysis and I have the following practice problem:

Let $P(z)=a_n z^n+\dots+a_1 z+a_0$ with $a_n,a_0\neq 0$, and assume $P(z)\neq 0$ on $|z|=1$. Let $P^*(z)=\overline{a_0}z^n+\overline{a_1}z^{n-1}+\dots+\overline{a_n}$. Prove that if $|a_0/a_n|>1$, then $P(z)$ and $\overline{a_0}P(z)-a_n P^*(z)$ have the same number of zeros in $|z|<1$.

I believe this problem should be solved with Rouche's theorem: if $|P(z)|=|P^*(z)|$ on $|z|=1$, then we may take $f(z)=\overline{a_0}P(z)$, $g(z)=-a_n P^*(z)$, and we have $|f(z)|>|g(z)|$ on $|z|=1$ and the result follows.

However, I am unable to show $|P(z)|=|P^*(z)|$ on $|z|=1$. I am unsure if I am approaching this problem the right way. Any help is very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Note that $P^*(z) = z^n\overline{P(1/\overline{z})}$.

Comment: I see, so it is sufficient to show $|P(z)|=|P(1/\overline{z})|$ on $|z|=1$. But, because $|z|=1$, we have $1/\overline{z}=z/|z|^2=z$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Note that this is the Schur transformation which is the basis for the [Lehmer-Schur algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%E2%80%93Schur_algorithm) of root location and isolation